# How get the image src value

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, event-handling

I want to get the src of a image when i click the image .that is in a table column

structure be like of the table is

```
   <html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td img src=" xxx "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td img src=" xxx "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td img src=" xxx "></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

please tell me a way to get the src of that image when i click the image and also i want to send that src to another html page

Comment: Have you tried Regex in JS ?

Comment: The `img` attribute inside of a `td` tag is not valid...

Comment: No useful question. Add a click event by `yourobject.addEventListener('click', function(event){})` and use event.target.src or add `onclick="alert(this.src)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code.
`img` is an separate html tag. You cannot set it as an attribute of `td`.

SO you html will be like this

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src=" xxx ">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src=" xxx2 ">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src=" xxx3 ">3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

To get the `src` value , you can use `getElementsByTagName` which will give you a collection of all images.

Then loop through it and add `addEventListener` inside a `closure`. You can also use `getAttribute` the get any attribute of the tag

**JS**

```
// get all the images
var getAllImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
// loop through it
for (var i = 0; i < getAllImages.length; i++) {
  (function(x) {  // closure starts here
    getAllImages[x].addEventListener('click', function() {

      alert(this.getAttribute('src'))
})
  }(i))  // pass the value of i
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4v6e91/2/)

Comment: Adding an event listener for each image could lead to memory issues, especially if the page has hundreds or more images, which might eventually cause the browser to crash. Also, if the images are added and removed from the DOM dynamically, this could lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html is incorrect.Please correct your html like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td> <img src=" xxx " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <img src=" xxx " /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <img src=" xxx " /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And to get `src` of `image` clicked use this

```
$(function () {
  $("img").click(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    window.location = "yourpage.html?src=" + src;
   });
});
```

Also you will need to include `jquery library` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const img = document.querySelector('img');

.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  alert(event.target.getAttribute('src'));
});
```

Comment: [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns the first element matching the selectors (or null), so that only works for the first image...

Answer (score 0):

A table cell (i.e. [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)) does not have valid attributes `img` and `src`, though it could have a `style` attribute that contains [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'TD') {
      document.getElementById('imgSrc').value = event.target.style.backgroundImage.replace(/(url\(")|("\))/g, '');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div>Click on an image to have its src attribute set as the value of the text input below:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fff263875808fbce8d846947c6d56449?s=32&d=identicon')">
       1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/616931b5c5ba8790a191fa6aea465c65?s=32&d=identicon')">
       2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56e1fa920ed4243286b8e62ab4fbdfef?s=32&d=identicon')">
        3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Image src:
  <div><input type="text" id="imgSrc" size="80" readonly /></div>
</div>
```

A more common way would be to have an [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag with a *src* attribute.

To answer your "question":

> tell me a way to get the src of that image when i click the image and also i want to send that src to another html page

Use JavaScript- and I recommended a technique called [Event delegation](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/). Bind an event handler for click events using with [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the event [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) (to know when the page is loaded) and then observe clicks on the document with a single callback like in the example below. This way there is only one event listener for the whole page instead of one per image, which could lead to memory-leaks, etc. The value of the input can be submitted with a form or sent to another page (e.g. with an AJAX request).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'IMG') {
      document.getElementById('imgSrc').value = event.target.src;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>Click on an image to have its src attribute set as the value of the text input below:
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
       1 <img src=" https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fff263875808fbce8d846947c6d56449?s=32&d=identicon " />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
       2 <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/616931b5c5ba8790a191fa6aea465c65?s=32&d=identicon" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3 <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56e1fa920ed4243286b8e62ab4fbdfef?s=32&d=identicon" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Image src:
  <input type="text" id="imgSrc" size="75" />
</div>
```

If you use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), the code can be simplified, like in the example below, utilizing [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), etc. [This article](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) about event delegation with jQuery (using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) method) may also be helpful.

```js
$(_ => {
  $(document).click(event => {
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'IMG') {
       $('#imgSrc').val(event.target.src);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1 <img src=" https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fff263875808fbce8d846947c6d56449?s=32&d=identicon" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2 <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/616931b5c5ba8790a191fa6aea465c65?s=32&d=identicon" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3 <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/56e1fa920ed4243286b8e62ab4fbdfef?s=32&d=identicon" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- removed 1 from table1 -->
  Image src:
  <input type="text" id="imgSrc" size="75" />
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery actually supports event delegation natively: `$(document).on('click', 'img', function(event) { ...` https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thanks - I have added that resource to my paragraph about jQuery